# Elementos encima de mapa google maps (Nativo) Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic, angularjs-2.0

Al momento de colocar un elemento HTML encima del mapa de Google Maps usando Ionic 2, no puedo darle click a dichos elementos , es como si el elemento no estuviera ahí y el click lo toma es el mapa.

Comment: Con CSS ponle `z-index` al elemento que le quieres dar click. A ver si con eso te fuciona.

Comment: El problema no es a nivel de CSS, parace un conflicto con el mapa nativo

Comment: Cómo estás añadiendo ese HTML? Es un overlay del mapa, un plugin, o es un elemento HTML escrito en duro desde el principio?

Comment: Es un elemento Html que se encuentra posicionado encima del mapa. @amenadiel

Comment: Ya, pero es hijo del  body, es hijo de otro div, es hijo del mismo div que el mapa?

Comment: @amenadiel Es hijo de <ion-content> y esta al mismo nivel del Mapa, osea son hermanos.

Comment: @AntonioSierraHurtado, ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Si añades el mapa por typescript se genera después. Hace poco he tenido que hacer un mapa dentro de un slide y al final optamos por el api de mapas estáticos de [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro?hl=es-419) ya que al darle al slide se movia el mapa y era incomodo.

código que se descarto:

```
 <ion-slide >
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-2></ion-col>
            <ion-col col-8 (click)="onClickedItem()">Ruta</ion-col>
            <ion-col col-2></ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
          <button ion-item (click)="onClickedItem()">
            Mi Ruta
          </button>
          <ion-item ><div #map id="map2"></div></ion-item>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-slide>
```

Si pones el código puedo ayudarte mejor.